# How to pass data into a custom table having foreign key of identity aspnetuserTable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity

I am trying to make relation relationship of AspNetUser Table with the StaffHotel Table and trying to pass value to the staff table when a user is doing registration.

[image: Staff Table]

[image: Application User Class]

when i migrate it,it creates the foreign key successfully.

[image: Entity]

But when i am trying to pass the value of id of AspnetUser Table to ApplicationUser_Id of the StaffHotel Table It is not saving the data.And showing the Problem that '`StaffHotel`' does not contain the defination of '`ApplicationUser_Id`'

[image: Register Method of the account Controller]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ur StaffHotel model add ApplicationUser_Id . framework should automatically detect it as foreign key. if not use foreign key annotation.